# How to Highlight and Display Default Validator Message?

Tags: angular, validation

This [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p44rni?file=src/app/app.component.ts), I'd like to learn how to:

1. highlight the input box and make **Required* in red
2. display a DEFAULT error message from validator when it fails `minLength(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeb, you has a type error when defined the FormGroup, see that if we has two or more validators you pass an array of validators

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  uname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]] //<--is an array
});
```

About the class we can has in styles.css some like

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {   //<--is necesary the "input", else a custom form
                                //control will be bordered too
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If we want only when "submited" we can use, e.g.

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched.submitted {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And use a variable in our ts

```
submitted :boolean=false;
```

And our input add `[class.submitted]`

```
<input [class.submitted]="submitted" type="text" formControlName="uname" ..>
```

About the repeater there're several aproach. One can be create a custom-error, one component like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-error',
  template: `
    <small class="error" *ngIf="isInvalid" >
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </small>
`,
styles:[`
.error{
  color:red
}
`]
})
export class ErrorComponent {
  @Input() submitted:boolean=true;
  get isInvalid() {
    const control = this.form.form.get(this.controlName);
    return this.submitted && control.touched && control.invalid && (this.error ? control.errors[this.error] : true);
  }
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() private form: FormGroupDirective,
    @Attribute("controlName") private controlName,
    @Attribute("error") private error) { }
}
```

Allow us write some like

```
//if we want not wait to submitted and a unique Validators
<custom-error controlName="uname" >Required</custom-error>

//if there're an unique Validators
<custom-error [submitted]="submitted" controlName="uname" >Required</custom-error>

//if we severals validators
<custom-error [submitted]="submitted" error="required" controlName="uname" >Required</custom-error>
```

We can imagine another kinds of "custom-errors" that only show one error

```
//this "defaultErrors should be in a external file and completed with other erros
//this allow us reemplace case we want "localize" our app

export const defaultErrors = {
  required: (error) => `This field is required`,
  minlength: ({ requiredLength, actualLength }) => `Expect ${requiredLength} but got ${actualLength}`,
  default:'field invalid' //<--add a string with the default error
}

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-error-unique',
  template: `
    <small class="error" *ngIf="hasError" >
       {{hasError}}
    </small>
`,
styles:[`
.error{
  color:red
}
`]
})
export class ErrorUniqueComponent {
   errors=defaultErrors
   @Input() submitted:boolean=true;
   @Input('errors') set _(value)
   {
       this.errors={...defaultErrors,...value}
   }

  @Input() submitted:boolean=true;
  @Input() errors:any=defaultErrors;

  get hasError() {
    const control = this.form.form.get(this.controlName);
    const invalid=this.submitted && control.touched && control.invalid
    let error=null
    if (invalid)
    {
       Object.keys(this.errors).forEach(x=>{
          if (control.errors[x] && !error)
          {
            error=this.errors[x](control.errors[x])
          }
       })
       if (!error)
            error=this.defaultErrors.default

    }
    return  error
  }
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() private form: FormGroupDirective,
    @Attribute("controlName") private controlName,
    @Attribute("error") private error) { }

}
```

In  [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2c9f5a?file=src%2Fapp%2Ferror-unique.component.ts) thre're the two custom-errors components

Even we can imagine that appears magically. Well, Netanel Basal think about it before us: see [this great entry blog](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this style to `styles.css`

```
.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

then something like this to input:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="uname"  placeholder="Enter Name..." [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': myForm.controls?.uname.errors && (myForm.controls?.uname.dirty || myForm.controls?.uname.touched) }">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufqzce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.html)

Comment: `has-error` not in effect in Demo, added it as in-line `style` still the same. Maybe missing something?

Comment: @Jeb50 I updated my answer and demo to include also `touched`

Comment: Angular add the classes for you: see the docs:https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes (you only need defined the .css in your "styles.css" or in your component

Comment: @Eliseo I was hoping for something _default_ in which Angular will display them if no customized msg passed in, any such exists? Else current implementation needs lots of typing **for each** violation on **each control**: `<div *ngIf="control1.errors?.minlength">At least 4 char.</div>` ... `<div *ngIf="controlX.errors?.required">`

Comment: @robert Seems `minlength` or `minLength` is not recognized. For example `<em *ngIf="myForm.hasError('minlength', 'uname') && myForm.controls?.uname.touched">*4+ hasError</em>` and 
`<em *ngIf="myForm.controls?.uname.errors?.minlength && (myForm.controls?.uname.dirty || myForm.controls?.uname.touched)">*4+</em>`

Comment: @Eliseo The built-in class are very helpful even though I can't attach any msg into it. Thank you!

Comment: @robert Gave an UP. Thank you for providing some insight and demo!